# Understanding Sinon.js's yield(), yields(), and callsArg()

Tags: javascript, sinon

What is the difference between

- `stub.yield([arg1, arg2, ...])`
- `spy.yields([arg1, arg2, ...])`
- `stub.callsArg(index)`

in the [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) stub library?

`stub.yield()` is the only one that I've been able to grasp:

```
  stub = sinon.stub(API, 'call_remote');
  callback = sinon.spy();
  API.call_remote('help', callback);
  @stub.yield( "solution!" );
  @stub.calledOnce.should.be.true;
  @callback.calledOnce.should.be.true;
  @callback.args[0][0].should.eql( "solution!" );
```

As tested with should.js, would have all assertions pass.

Are there similar test patterns for `stub.yields()` and `stub.callsArg(index)`?

The documentation does not provide any examples to clarify these other two methods but I am curious about them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe the methods, as outlined in the documentation, are as follows:

- `spy.yield`
- `stub.yields`
- `stub.callsArg`

The main difference between `yields` and `callsArg` can be found in sinon's documentation for yields:

> If a method accepts more than one callback, you need to use callsArg to have the stub invoke other callbacks than the first one.

`yields` will call the *first* function argument it encounters with any optional arguments you provide to it. `callsArg` will attempt to invoke the function argument at the *given index*  within that call's `arguments` object, and does not pass any arguments to it (you can use `callArgWith` for that behavior).

`spy.yield` is very similar to `stub.yields` except it is part of the spy API and it calls all callbacks passed to it.

Here's some examples demonstrating the differences (forgive me if the examples are a bit contrived):

Yields:

```
var fn = sinon.expectation.create().withArgs(1, 2);
var stub = sinon.stub().yields(1, 2);
stub(fn);
fn.verify();
```

CallsArg:

```
var f1 = sinon.expectation.create().never();
var f2 = sinon.expectation.create().once();
var stub = sinon.stub().callsArg(1);
stub(f1, f2);
f1.verify();
f2.verify();
```

Yield:

```
var f1 = sinon.expectation.create().once();
var f2 = sinon.expectation.create().once();
var stub = sinon.stub().yield();
stub(f1, f2);
f1.verify();
f2.verify();
```